# How would I fix Winforms controls not drawing on under .net7

Tags: .net, panel

I've created a new winforms application with .NET 7, added the F!Sharp github package as my application requires it.  I have made zero other modifications to the app beyond that.

Now, when I go to add any type of panel control, i can place it in designer and set its properties, but for the love of god I can't get it to actually show when the application is run.

I tried running this under .NET 7 as this is the minimum targeted framework for the library (F1Sharp) that I'm using.  I can't find any reason for the panels to not display as all attributes are set correctly.